# Selecting a XML node with LINQ, and modifying

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I've got the following XML:

```
<Config>
   <Book>
      <Name> Book Name #1 </Name>
      <Available In>
               <Country>US</Country>
               <Country>Canada</Country>
      </Available In>
   </Book>
</Config>
```

I need to find all instances of Book which are available in a specific country, and then introduce a node underneath "Available In". My selection statement fails anytime I add the where statement:

```
XElement xmlFile = XElement.Load(xmlFileLocation);
var q = (from c in xmlFile.Elements(“Book”)
           where c.Elements(Country).Value == "Canada"
           select c;
```

.Value can't be resolved, and toString give me the entire subnode in stringform. I need to select all books in a particular country so that I can then update them all to include a new locale node, ex:

```
<Config>
       <Book>
          <Name> Book Name #1 </Name>
          <Available In>
                   <Country>US</Country>
                   <Country>Canada</Country>
          </Available In>
          <LocaleIDs>
               <LocalID> 3066 </LocaleID>
          <LocaleIDs>
       </Book>
    </Config>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use `Value` on the result of calling `Elements` which returns a *sequence* of elements. That's not going to work - it doesn't make any sense. You want to call it on a single element at a time.

Additionally, you're trying to look for *direct* children of `Book`, which ignores the `Available In` element, which isn't even a valid element name...

I suspect you want something like:

```
var query = xmlFile.Elements("Book")
                   .Where(x => x.Descendants("Country")
                                .Any(x => (string) x == "Canada"));
```

In other words, find `Book` elements where any of the descendant `Country` elements has a text value of "Canada".

You'll still need to fix your XML to use valid element names though...